# Add UIView at bottom of UITableViewCell programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiimageview, chat

I'm working on a instant messaging app. The user can send text messages, for which I'm using a UITextView inside the custom tableview cells. The user should be able to send all kinds of multimedia data, such as images, documents and videos.
  [image]

Inside my table view cell I have both a textView and a UIImageView in a stackView and I can send the respective kinds of data. If there is no text, I hide the TextView. If there is no Image, I hide the image.

The problem is: to scale the app, I'd have to add a new container for documents, another one for videos, another one for audio files and hide all the other containers that have no data added to it. It's a garbage solution, but it was the only one that I found.

Knowing from the backend what kind of data is sent, how could I programatically add a container view in which I make the setup on the spot? I was thinking of having a textView as default and an empty View and inside cellForRowAt just add the needed elements.

Comment: You can use different cells for respective messages. Don't make cell hazy. It will be an optimal solution for garbage UI controls in TableViewCell.

Answer (score 1):

I would try to create several cells which you dequeue in cellForRowAt by checking for a criteria, e.g.:

```
    if userPost.images != nil {
                let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Identifier1", for: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell
return cell
            } else {
                let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Identifier2", for: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell
                return cell
            }
```

With this solution, you can create a cell that nicely fits the data a user sent another user. Just check for any criteria you want and return the according cell.

Hope it helped!

Comment: Well, I already have 2 custom cells: one for sent messages and one for received messages, since the UI differs a bit. By going your way wouldn't I have double the numbers of custom cells for data display? 2 for images, 2 for 2 documents, 2 for audio files, 2 for videos.
I was just hoping maybe there's a cleaner solution for such a task...

Comment: You could use inheritance: You have a basic cell (eg username and the message) and other cells. One other cell could have an image additionally to the text. This means, the image cell inherits from the standard cell and then you only have to extend it with the image by adding it.

According to your initial question: Yes, you would have a lot of cells but I am not sure if you can anyhow change that. I mean, you could calculate the height of the views needed for a cell and then set the size accordingly in sizeForItemAt and add the views in cellForRowAt.